# Using Columns from Table in R to create New Table

Tags: r

I am very new to **R** and R studio and I have successfully important a table from sas7bdat into R studio.

Now I want to use columns 7, 8, 10, 11, and 12 from that table to make a new table.

Once I do that, would anyone know how to add up the numeric values in those columns into a new column at the end?

Comment: Just do `df1$newCol <- rowSums(df1[, c(7:8, 10:12)])`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
df2 <- df1[,c(7, 8, 10, 11, ,12)]
df2$total <- rowSums(df2)
```